# PySerial Error on Raspberry 3

Tags: pi-3, serial, software-installation

So I am trying to setup the code on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B so make it so it can read and write from a Serial Port.  I installed Python 2 and 3 versions of PySerial with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

So I should have the most up to date versions of PySerial installed correctly?  Well when I was running my code I was just trying to output the port settings with:

```
print(port.get_settings())
```

Which when I run the module gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'get_settings()'
```

So I went and changed the code to the old name for the method:

```
print(port.getSettingsDict)
```

And this worked.  So obviously I don't have the newest version of PySerial on my Pi.  So I went to do the install again and was told I already have the newest version on my Pi. However, I can obviously tell I don't because of the errors I am getting.

So how would I go about fixing this?  Am I just not making the correct terminal calls to install PySerial?

Answer (score 2):

As you have found the version available in the APT repositories are not always the most up to date.

You can use pip to install a newer version with the following command:

```
pip install pyserial
```

**Note:** You may need to run the above command with the following options:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyserial
```

or [download](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) the archive:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/8d/88/cf848688ae011085a6da5a470740dafa3a4b105f84a5f79c3b720c19279c/pyserial-3.3.tar.gz#md5=6afe4c2e47bcec6eb7051b8c1ce19d52
```

Unpack the archive:

`tar -xzf pyserial-3.3.tar.gz`

enter the pyserial-3.3 directory:

```
cd pyserial-3.3
```

and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

for Python 2.x

or:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

For Python 3.x.

**Note:** You may need to remove the older packages you installed using apt first. You can remove them with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-serial
sudo apt-get remove python3-serial
```

Comment: Where is the pyserial-x.y directory?

Comment: @Skitzafreak It will be in the directory where you downloaded and extracted the source file see above edits. The pip method is easier.

Comment: SoI ran the upgrade through pip, and after running `print(serial.VERSION)` I am still being shown that my PySerial version is 2.6

Comment: I get 3.3 did you use sudo amd the upgrade flag? Are you doing this in Python 2 or 3

Comment: yeah i used sudo and the upgrade flag.  I tried it again, I'm still on 2.6 :\

Comment: try this sudo apt-get remove python-serial and  sudo apt-get remove python3-serial. You may have to redo the pip install

Comment: I uninstalled it, but pip just reinstalled 2.7 again for some reason.  So I manually downloaded 3.3 and installed it through the non-pip half of your original answer.  It's working now.  Thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome, @Skitzafreak. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that upvoting and/or accepting a helpful answer is the Raspberry Pi way of saying thank you.